# Searching a particular letters or words from the string of database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, search, windows-forms-designer

I have a database named sang.mdf, it contains fields like slno, date, name, amount.  I want to search the datas entered in the name field of the database. ie, If the field name contains data "Abijith". Then I search "Abi" in the text box i want to view "Abijith" from the database.  Can you help me..

```
sql connection con = new sqlconnection(@"connection string");
string abi = "select billno, date, name, total from sannew where name = '" + textBox3.Text + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter sdaa = new SqlDataAdapter(abi, con);
                DataSet dss = new DataSet();
                sdaa.Fill(dss);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dss.Tables[0];
```

In this method I want to type full text "Abijith" to search and view. But when i search "Abi" The search item is not found

Comment: Where is the code? what issue you are facing with the code? Do you know how to query data from database using ADO.NET classes?

Comment: I need codes in c# visual studio windows forms

Comment: <code>  sqlconnection con = new sqlconnection(@"connection string"); string abi = "select billno, date, name, total from sannew where name = '" + textBox3.Text + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter sdaa = new SqlDataAdapter(abi, con);
                DataSet dss = new DataSet();
                sdaa.Fill(dss);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dss.Tables[0];

Comment: Why not put that code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

use the LIKE operator in your query and the % wildcard.

```
"select billno, date, name, total from sannew where name LIKE '%" + textBox3.Text + "%'";
```

NOTE: this method of concatenating strings from user text input into query is bad for many reasons, one of which is that you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).